# Typescript: How can I cast a variable as an element of an array?

Tags: typescript

Array:

```
const myStrings = ["one", "two", "three"];
const newString = "two";
```

`newString` will simply be of type `string`, but I want the type to be something like `element of myStrings`.

How can I do this if the values in the array may or may not change?

Comment: I **think** you want [type literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) but it's not clear. What does *something like element of myStrings* mean?

Comment: ```newString``` would be a string that exists in myStrings

Comment: Well, ALL VOTES are subjective. *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. This seems to tick (as a minimum) two of those boxes.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I think you should use enum for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typeof myStrings[number]`, but only if `myStrings` has `as const` telling TypeScript that its contents don't change:

```typescript
const myStrings = ["one", "two", "three"] as const;
type MyStringsElement = typeof myStrings[number]; // For convenience
const newString: MyStringsElement = "two";
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwMpQE4EswHMIwLwwDaAROAKbEA0MxUA7iFTVABapkUC6MAhrqJCgBuAFBQEABzIwAssjSYcAUQA2ZOGTCwC4qSABm8eRmwRCYAK5wARmVSdRA6DDBk6KE1gBcs44oiq6pqw+MwMxKJAA)

With the `myStrings` contents you've shown, the type of `newString` will be `"one" | "two" | "three"`. That's a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of three [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), meaning that the only valid values for `newString` are `"one"`, `"two'`, or `"three"` (as compile-time constant values).

(Note: `typeof myStrings[number]` is evaluated by TypeScript as `(typeof myStrings)[number]`, which may be surprising. I used to think I needed the parentheses, and I'm not sure it's not best to have them for clarity even if they aren't needed... :-) )